# Entity Framework using different connection strings?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 projects in my solution:

1. `Server.API`

This is a web api project. The `web.config` has a section for `<connectionStrings>`, and there's one connection string available.

2. `Server.Model`

This is where 2 models (database first) are located. The `app.config` also has a section for `<connectionStrings>`, and there are 2 connection strings, one for each model.

The initial solution was developed on one machine. Now I'm using a second machine.

When I try to update the model from the database (right-click in EF designer), I get to choose my data connection, and in the list of available connections, I get the one in the `Server.API`!

How does the designer know about this connection, and why doesn't it list the 2 connections that are the `Server.Model` project where the actual `.edmx` files are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably developed `Server.API` on the second machine, so Visual Studio (not the edmx) knows you previously used that specific connection for *some* task that required a connection (not even which task). It hasn't stored the other two yet.

Besides that, apparently the other two databases in the App.config of `Server.Model` are not accessible from the second machine, otherwise the Update Wizard would have used them without showing the "choose connection" page.